# You can only use an ID once, what exactly does that mean?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've read that you can only use an ID once in CSS. I've run into something strange that I don't understand and I was wondering if anyone can shed any light on this?

My header contains a basket button with the following markup:

```
<div id="basket-button-desktop">
    <div id="basket-button-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Then there is a media query that replaces the menu button above with the following version when the window is less than 580px.

```
<div id="basket-button-mobile">
    <div id="basket-button-inner"></div>
</div>
```

I have a jQuery animation that upon scroll, changes the colour of both the header and `#basket-button-inner The outer divs in the examples above both have separate IDs, whereas the inner divs nested inside have the same ID.

When the screen is wider than 580px, the background colour of `#basket-button-inner` obeys the jQuery and changes from blue to pink as you scroll down the page. When the screen is below 580px wide, it ignores the value set in the jQuery and it stays blue.

Why is this – is it because I've used the same ID twice in my markup?

When I read that you can't use the same ID twice, I assumed it meant that you can't give two different objects the same ID and expect different CSS codes you give them to work. I didn't think it meant you can't put the same object with the same ID in different places throughout a page.

When I change the ID to a class for this div, it works.

I'm not sure what to make of this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I've put two jsFiddles below, the first one is the problem one with IDs, the second is the one with the IDs replaced with classes.

I've included the code from the first fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/37/

https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/38/

**HTML**

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="header-inner">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="basket-button-desktop">
            <div class="basket-button-inner"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="basket-button-mobile">
            <div class="basket-button-inner"></div>
        </div>

   </div>
</header>

<div class="content">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: darkorange;
}
 body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    transition: all .5s;
}
#header-inner {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
 ul#menu {
    display: inline-block;
}
 ul#menu li {
    color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
#basket-button-desktop {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 75px;
    height: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#basket-button-mobile {
    display: none;
}
.basket-button-inner {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin: 15px;
    background:blue;
}
.content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 680px) {
    #basket-button-desktop {
        display: none;
    }
    #basket-button-mobile {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        width: 75px;
        height: 55px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $(window).scroll(function() {

      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 75) {

           $("#header-inner").css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "top": "-55px",
            "background-color": "#fff",
            "box-shadow": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 0px 0px",
            "visibility": "hidden"
        });

        $(".basket-button-inner").css({
            "background": "pink"
        });

    } else {

      $("#header-inner, .basket-button-inner").removeAttr("style");
    }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {

        $("#header-inner").css({
            "transition": "all .5s",
            "transform": "translate3d(0px,55px,0px)",
            "visibility": "visible",
        });

    } else {

        $('#header-inner').css({
            "transform": "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)"
        });

    }


    });

});
```

Comment: IDs must be unique per document. Use CSS classes instead that's what they're for.

Comment: First - you are repeating the ID on the page - just because the ID is within different containers, doesn't mean it's not present. SINGULAR use of an ID within a document. Second, why do you  even have two different containers? They seem to do exactly the same, why not just use the one container, with the inner-container inside, and modify it using @media-queries as needed?

Comment: IDs need to be unique in an HTML page, not in a CSS stylesheet.  You can use the same id as many times as you want in the stylesheet.

Comment: In addition to using class selectors instead of ID's, you would make your life much easier if, instead of setting inline CSS with jQuery at certain scroll positions, you toggled classes that inherit the CSS (from your stylesheet) at those same scroll positions.

Comment: Hi Lifehack, thanks for the advice. I actually had it set up like this before, but because I was using multiple jQuery scripts that toggled classes onto the header and other elements nested inside it, I found that the transition times kept clashing, as I could only add one transition rule to each element. Do you know of a way around this problem?

Comment: And @junkfoodjunkie - This is a pretty stripped down version of the code. On my actual website, the button is a hyperlink to a page when the browser is full width, but on mobiles it loses the link and becomes a button for a push menu

Comment: And? What does that have to do with having two containers?

Comment: Maybe I've got this wrong – is there a way of disabling a hyperlink at a media query? I also did it this way because the button in the full width layout is nested in a nav menu that is set to `display:none` when the screen reaches mobile/tablet width. I nested the button in there because my header uses a flex layout with `justify-content:space-between` and this ensures that both the nav and the button sit at the end of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids must be unique within a document (like an entire HTML page). [That's the hard and fast rule set forth by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute): once you use an ID in one place, you shouldn't use it again somewhere else within that document.

Why? Well, think about what would happen when you try to run something like `document.getElementById('basket-button-inner')` against your document.

What element would get returned? Here, javascript expects IDs to be unique, but they're not in your case. So, which element would that snippet select?

By violating the rule, you're going to cause strange and wonderful things to happen when you use built-ins and other functions that expect IDs to be unique.

Will your page display if you re-use that ID a bunch of times? Sure. Will elements with that duplicate ID be styled properly? You bet. Will your page break in strange and unusual (and hard-to-debug) ways, especially when you try to select one of those elements with javascript? Yep.

For styles that should be repeated among any number of elements, use classes. [This is what they're for](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/global-attributes.html#classes), and they can be used as many times on as many different elements as your document requires.

Think of it this way: classes define a single "classification" to which any number of elements can belong (in your case, it's `basket-button-inner`). That's what they have in common: they're all buttons that are members of that particular classification; they just happen to display on mobile and desktop. An ID is a unique thing to which *one and only one* element can belong. That's it. If you use an ID, you're saying "I expect there to be only one of these things because it's so unique I gave it an ID."

Generally speaking, you'll want to be reserved in giving things IDs. Things deserving of IDs include stuff that's really important, like an element you're going to refer to in a script; or an element from which you want to create a new styling context as IDs are very powerful, very specific selectors that are hard to override)

Comment: Thanks for such a long and comprehensive answer. So if there are elements in my website that I know I won't call twice in my HTML, like header, footer, side-menu etc.. is it worth giving these IDs instead of classes? I read somewhere that it makes the website slightly faster as the browser finds them sooner because they are more specific. Having said that, if I'm being conservative in what I give IDs, it probably won't make much difference to speed if it is only a few things that have them.

Comment: It is best to only use id's if you're specifically targetting a single item with javascript. Otherwise you want to use classes.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll bear this in mind. What I'd done was misunderstood and spent hours going through my website and changing all of the classes to id's.. seems like a pretty stupid idea now. But I did notice that it seemed a lot smoother when I had it that way round. By this I mean the CSS/jQuery animations.

Answer (score 1):

this css  is for a class .basket-button-inner  mean class basket-button-inner

```
.basket-button-inner {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   float: right;
   margin: 15px;
  background:blue;
}
```

You should use   class not id for basket-button-inner

```
 <div id="basket-button-desktop">
   <div class="basket-button-inner"></div>
</div>


<div id="basket-button-mobile">
   <div class="basket-button-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It means precisely what it says. An ID can only be used once on the page. When wanting to do the same thing to multiple elements you need to use a class instead of an ID. As a matter of fact it is better practice to only use class names unless you run into a situation where you need to target one specific element and only one element with javascript. IDs should almost never be used in CSS because they take the highest precedence and become hard to overwrite. `#header-inner` would be much better off as `.header-inner` but that is going to change your jQuery code as well. When using a classname as a jquery selector you get an array returned. So your jQuery would change from `$('#header-inner').css...` to `$('.header-inner').each(function() { $(this).css... });`

Comment: Thanks Caldwell, so if I were to change header-inner to a class, would I have to write the jQuery in the way you wrote in your answer? – `$('.header-inner').each(function() { $(this).css... });`  I had this as a class before and I just changed the '#' to a '.' and it worked fine.

Comment: It could be  the case that some jQuery functions like `.css` will effect all elements with that classname but for the most part you would need to change it. The reason why you need to change it is that the selector is returning and array and the `.each` function will loop through that array and let you do something to all of them.

I stopped using jQuery a long time ago so it could be the case that things have changed so that you can use the class selector without `.each` but if it doesn't work then that is why.