# Multiple Image Gallery: My For Loop Only Processes The First Group of Elements and Div. Why Wont It Apply To All The Code and Images?

Tags: javascript

I'm building an a page with 5 little image galleries on it. The galleries are a few thumbnails and a large main image. When you click the thumbnail it displays the image on the large main. I'm trying to apply a for loop to make the image clicking of the thumb nail to all the galleries. It works for the first block of images, click the thumb nail and its displayed on the main. The problem is that it doesnt work on the galleries that proceed the first little gallery.

Does anyone know why the loop only processes the first elements and div and how to fix?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

**My little galleries. I have five of them, but have only shown two here.**

```
<p>Animals</p>
<img src="Images\Sheltie Snow Day Art Print (7 x 7).png" id="main">
<div id="thumbnails">
<img src="Images\Border Collie Art Print, (8 x 10) Dog Art.png">
<img src="Images/Border Collie ORIGINAL Folk Painting (8 x 8).png  ">
<img src="Images/Chickadees Chat ORIGINAL Mini Painting.png">
</div>

<p>Flowers</p>
<img src="Images\Daisy Wildflower Abundance ORIGINAL Painting ( 7x7).png" id="main">
<div id="thumbnails">
<img src="Images/Wildflower Meadow Mini ORIGINAL Painting ( 7 x 7) Sunflower Landscape.png">
<img src="Images/wild flower (3) - Copy.png">
<img src="Images/Wildflower Meadow ORIGINAL Painting Mini Floral Landscap.png">
</div>
```

**Here's my loop that only works on the first block of elements, not the second. **

```
<script>
var thumbnails = document.getElementById("thumbnails")
var imgs = thumbnails.getElementsByTagName("img")
var main = document.getElementById("main")
var counter=0;


for(let i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
let img=imgs[i]

img.addEventListener("click",function(){
main.src=this.src
})
}
</script>
```

Comment: A `#thumbnails` `id` has to be unique at the document. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40493101/2569323 . 

Comment: `document.getElementById("thumbnails")` - This finds *one element* by its *unique* `id` value.  Perhaps you're looking to `getElementsByClassName` and loop over them?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` will only grab the first element on the page that matches that selector. You could use `getElementsByClassName` and attach listeners to all of the images, but there is a simpler method - [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/).

Event delegation allows you to add one listener to a parent (container) element that listens to all the events that "bubble up" the DOM from its child elements.

In this example I've attached that listener to the element with the `container` class.

The handler for that listener:

1. Checks to see if a) the element that was clicked was an image element and b) that it was within the `thumbnails` container.
2. If it is it sets the `src` of the `previousElementSibling` (the image element with the `selected` class) of its parent (the thumbnail container) to be its `src` value.

Because each group of selected and thumbnail images are clearly delineated you can add as many as you want.

```js
// Use event delegation to detect events from child elements
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  
  // If the clicked element is an image and
  // it's a thumbnail find the selected image container
  // and update its src property
  if (el.closest('img') && el.closest('.thumbnails')) {
    const selected = el.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
    selected.src = e.target.src;
  }
}
```

```css
.selected { width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid black; }
.thumbnails img { border: 3px solid lightgray; }
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <section>
    <h3>Animals</h3>
    <img src="https://i.pickadummy.com/index.php?imgsize=200x100&text=Animals&font=Capture%20It" class="selected">
    <div class="thumbnails">
      <img src="https://i.pickadummy.com/index.php?imgsize=200x100&text=Tiger&font=Capture%20It">
      <img src="https://i.pickadummy.com/index.php?imgsize=200x100&text=Mouse&font=Capture%20It">
      <img src="https://i.pickadummy.com/index.php?imgsize=200x100&text=Capybara&font=Capture%20It">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Flowers</h3>
    <img src="https://i.pickadummy.com/index.php?imgsize=200x100&text=Flowers&font=Capture%20It" class="selected">
    <div class="thumbnails">
      <img src="https://i.pickadummy.com/index.php?imgsize=200x100&text=Rose&font=Capture%20It">
      <img src="https://i.pickadummy.com/index.php?imgsize=200x100&text=Daisy&font=Capture%20It">
      <img src="https://i.pickadummy.com/index.php?imgsize=200x100&text=Cornflower&font=Capture%20It">
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Additional documentation

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)
- [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling)

Comment: Thank-you, so much! That worked nicely. It's a bit complicated for my level but I'll keep working breaking it down to smaller pieces. One problem it created is the main image is now blank pre-click. I've tried a few things but came seem to find a solution.

Comment: @JamesM you can give them a source if you don't want it blank. I've updated my answer accordingly, and also added some additional links to some documentation.